# In a N-way associative cache, how do we decide which "Way" to select?

Tags: computer-architecture, cache

[image]

I am having a hard time understanding the part of the cache after a Word has been selected by the 8:1 MUX. As far as I understand, the 2:1 MUX must have a select line coming from the MSB of the Index. But, the MSB of the Index only points to the last entry of Way-1/Way-2.

The way I am imagining this problem is by stacking the two "Ways" on top of each other. Then the cache will have 1024 sets. But, to index 1024 sets, index must have 10 bits, but here the Index is only 9 bits.

So how does the 2:1 MUX decide which Word to send to the processor?

Comment: It sends the one with the correct tag value. If neither has the correct tag, then you have a cache miss.